# Find (describe) the range of the complex function:

Tags: complex-analysis

So I'm new to Complex Analysis and this question about range is driving me mad...

Find (describe) the range of the complex function:

$f(z) = {e^{2z}},\mathrm{\ for \ z \ in \ the \ rectangular \ region \ }\{z = x +iy \ | \ 0 \le x \le \ln(2), {\pi \over 4} \le y \le {\pi \over 2}\}$

It is easy enough to rewrite $f(z)$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ in standard form and then define $w = u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$.....

$f(z) = {e^{2z}} = {e^{2x}}{e^{2iy}} = {e^{2x}}\cos2y + i{e^{2x}}\sin2y$

and so

$u(x,y) = {e^{2x}}\cos2y, \ v(x,y) = {e^{2x}}\sin2y$

But I am not sure how to proceed from here :(

Comment: The boundary of the rectangle will map to the boundary of the range.  What do you get if you plug some of these boundary equations into your expressions for $u$ and $v$?

Comment: For u(x,y): If I plug in (x = 0, y = pi/4) I get 0. Then if I plug in ( x = ln(2), y = pi/2) I get -4. For v(x,y): If I do the same, I get 1 and 0.

Comment: Those are points on the boundary, but you'll get more information if you plug in one equation at a time.  For instance, substituting $y = \pi/4$, we get $u(x, \pi/4) = 0$ and $v(x,\pi/4) = e^{2x}$.  As $x$ ranges in $[0, \ln(2)]$, this traces out a vertical segment in the $u,v$-plane from $(0,0)$ to $(0,4)$.  Try plugging each of the other conditions in one at a time and see what they trace out when you let the remaining variable vary.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, thanks!

Comment: Although I think it should be (0,1) to (0,4).

Answer (score 2):

If you think in polar co-ordinates you can stop at ${e^{2x}}{e^{2iy}}=r{e^{i\theta}}$

The first part is the distance from the origin, and the second part is the angle. So the distance from the origin ranges from ${e^{0}=1}$ to ${e^{2\ln(2)}}=4$, and the angle ranges from $\pi\over 2$ to $\pi$. The range is the entire "block arc" shape this covers.

Comment: Very nifty method. Thanks!